# Passing multidimensional array to php via ajax

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass a multidimensional array from my jquery script to a php  file which writes the values in the array to a mysql table. Here are my efforts so far but data is not inserted into the table. Any help appreciated.

**sourceblockstaffarray structure:**

|Userid|staffid|blockid|

with multiple rows so an example of the content of the array would be

|1|2|3|

|4|5|6|

|7|8|9|

**Ajax:**

```
 $.ajax

 ({

    url: 'tl2_post_staffonblock_via_array.php',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {staffarray: JSON.stringify(sourceblockstaffarray)},              
    success: function(data)
    {                   
    },
    error: function(data)
    {   
    }                   
});
```

**php:**

```
<?php

include ('tl2_config.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect($HOST_STRING, $USER_NAME, $USER_PASSWORD, $DATABASE_NAME);

$staffarray = json_decode( $_POST['staffarray'] );

foreach($staffarray as $m)
{
  $userid    = $m[0];
  $staffid   = $m[1];
  $blockid   = $m[2];
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO staffonblock (userid, 
  staffid, blockid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss",  $userid, $staffid, $blockid);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you see when you `var_dump($_POST)`? That is, does the array look like you expect when it arrives in your PHP code?

Comment: The old `mysql_query()` function has been dropped from PHP from version 7 - you should use mysqli or PDO. Why do you do that, when you have opened a mysqli connection? And if it's just a typo, you have the parameters in the wrong order. And to use parameters, you'll need to prepare the query before you execute it. I use PDO myself, and it's a little different, but in your code, how does it know which parameter is userid, which is staffid, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you need `json_decode` to change the json array to an array that PHP can iterate through.

```
$staffarray = json_decode( $_POST['staffarray'] );
```

Comment: Var_dump says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting '', or ';'

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a semi colon some place....